# Magento 2 adding version in css and js path when creating a custom theme

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.1.2 adding version in css and js path, like **version1483790821** when creating custom theme. Please have a look on the attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve above issue, run below query in your magento 2 database, it will insert a row in core_config_data table:

INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');